# err_connection_refused on Reactjs app when connecting to nodejs backend on other network machines

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm making an App that uses a Reactjs front end and node.js back end. On the server machine everything works and connects fine. When I try to access the app via localhost:4000 on a different machine, hardwired to the same network, the front end works, but it cannot connect to back end. I'm trying to fetch data from my node.js server with

```
componentDidMount(){
    console.log('REACT WORKING');
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/toDoList')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(res => {
        if (res.data ){
            console.log(res.data)
            this.setState({
                list: res.data
            })
        }
    });
    console.log(this.state.list)
}
```

When I use chromes inspect feature and look at the console 'REACT WORKING' is printed as expected but it is then followed with "GET http://localhost:3001/toDoList net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

When I go to that URL directly i'm shown the data that node.js is posting, but the react app fetch cannot seem to access it. Again, this only occurs on other machines on the network, the machine hosting the React and Node servers works as expected. I am aware there are similar questions posted, but I tried the solutions posted for those and nothing has worked. I tried changing chromes proxy setting and it didn't change anything.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is the node.js back end running on a different computer than the client?

Comment: I guess this is a cors error. Are you using express on your backend? If you are try with this middleware, it's pretty straight forward : https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: @terrymorse Yes the node.js and react apps are running on one computer, and the client trying to use the app is on a different computer hard wired into the save network. The back end is an express app.

Comment: @Trisma I'm already using cors in my express backend. I don't think the app is even getting that far.

Comment: @form3ds The client is trying to access the server at `localhost`, which is the local address of the client. I don't see how that could connect to the server.

Comment: @terrymorse Thanks! I changed the fetch to fetch from the ip of the server machine instead of the client and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue, and as mentioned by [Terrymorse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3113485/terrymorse) I just removed that localhost part inside fetch function and added my own IP address. It worked and I am able to fetch the required details.

`fetch('http://<my_ip_address>:3001/toDoList')`

I was using Ubuntu machine and with `ip r` command I am able to get my IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with NodeJS v17, DNS resolution prefers IPV6 addresses.  If your server is not listening on IPV6, localhost will translate to the address ::1 where your server is **not** listening.

You can either configure your NodeJS application's DNS preference, or do as told in the other answer, which is specify either the loopback's address **127.0.0.1** or some other adapter's IP address.

```js
import dns from 'dns';

dns.setDefaultResultOrder('ipv4first');
```